# ¿Por qué una "melopea" es una borrachera?

Tags: etimología, historia

En el diccionario de la lengua de la RAE la tercera acepción de [melopea](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OqkElYv) es

> 3. f. coloq. Embriaguez, borrachera.

Esa acepción fue incluida por primera vez en la edición de 1950, aunque figuraba ya en el diccionario de Rodriguez Navas de 1918.

Las acepciones habituales de **melopea** son "Música vocal", "Arte de producir melodías" o "Entonación rítmica con que puede recitarse algo en verso o en prosa."

¿Cómo adquirió esa nueva acepción?

Comment: Será por la afición de los borrachos a cantar? xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por asociación con el estado de embriagues y la música, fiesta, canto y jolgorio.

Según [la entrada para "melopea" en etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?melopea), que explica que la palabra viene del latín *melopoeia* (y esta a su vez del griego) que viene a significar "el arte de producir música o melodías"

> la tendencia fácil al canto y al jolgorio de los que andan ebrios, ha provocado este uso específico [borrachera] de la palabra melopea.

La entrada en [wiktionary](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/melopea) añade:

> Estado de embriaguez, especialmente si produce un ánimo festivo que induce al afectado a cantar o expresar de otra manera su ánimo.

Al igual que pasó con "[tajada](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/tag/melopea/)", por la asociación, melopea pasó a denominar al estado de embriaguez.